# Print values in a struct array, C++

Tags: c++

I have an imposed .hpp containing theses things :

```
  enum class        TileType : uint16_t
    {
      EMPTY         = 0,
      BLOCK         = 1,
      OBSTACLE      = 2,
      EVIL_DUDE     = 3,
      EVIL_SHOOT    = 4,
      MY_SHOOT      = 5,
      POWERUP       = 6,
      OTHER         = 7
    };
```

and

```
  struct        GetMap
  {
    CommandType     type;
    uint16_t        width;
    uint16_t        height;
    TileType        tile[0];
  } __attribute__((packed));
```

My question is, after creating the variable :

```
GetMap *map = new GetMap[(10 * 10) * sizeof(TileType)];
```

and filled it with values like this :

```
map->tile[(y * 10) + x] = TileType::BLOCK;
```

How can I print the entire **GetMap**'s **tiles** values on terminal ? I've thinked of using casts, but I have some problems with them.

Comment: You cannot have array variables of zero length in C++.

Comment: That "struct hack" from C is not a valid C++ code. (And shouldn't be used in modern C too.)

Comment: So you stored width=10 and height=10 as part of writing the values.  Use the same loop to read them back.  (also this is error prone. If you use a c++ container you know it will be handled correctly at every step -- allocate, write, read, destruct, cleaned up on exception)